# parsing a text file for integers on a given line with python

Tags: python, parsing, matplotlib

I've got this test suite that outputs test results as a text file.
Here is a sample:

```
    File Opened: Tuesday, June 26, 2016, 10:17:13 AM

File Opened: Tuesday, June 26, 2016, 10:17:29 AM
Radio Test BER LOOP BACK successful
Radio Test PAUSE successful
Radio Test BER LOOP BACK successful

File Opened: Tuesday, June 28, 2016, 10:18:11 AM
Bits received                    10152
Bits in error                       117
Access code bit errors     0
Packets received             49
Packets expected            2707
Packets w/ header error  0
Packets w/ CRC error      0
Packets w/ uncorr errors 0
Sync timeouts                  3
==================================
Bits received                    10368
Bits in error                       85
Access code bit errors     0
Packets received             52
Packets expected            2758
Packets w/ header error  0
Packets w/ CRC error      0
Packets w/ uncorr errors 0
Sync timeouts                  1
==================================
Bits received                    10152
Bits in error                       93
Access code bit errors     0
Packets received             49
Packets expected            2707
Packets w/ header error  0
Packets w/ CRC error      0
Packets w/ uncorr errors 0
Sync timeouts                  3
```

I'm trying to extract the number after `Bits received` and `Bits in error`, and divide them to get a percentage.

Then, I'd like to plot those as a scatter plot with `matplotlib.pyplot`.

I'm having a hard time getting those numbers out of this file, however...I'm messing up something with how I'm parsing this.

Either way, I'm just feeling my way through this, and I'm sure I'm not doing this the most elegant way possible.  This seems like such a simple task for Python and I'm surely making it much harder than it needs to be.

How would you handle this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two arrays, once for the `received` data and one for the `error` data, then just loop through the file and parse:

```
receivedData = []
errorData = []
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("Bits received"):
            receivedData.append(int(line.split()[-1]))
        elif line.startswith("Bits in error"):
            errorData.append(int(line.split()[-1]))
        else:
            #do normal stuff with other lines
            pass
```

Comment: I like python a lot because it does everything, but it seems like you have to know everything before you can use it effectively.  `startswith`, `split`, `append` are seemingly unbelievable to me that they work reliably in the first place...Putting together a symphony with them is something I'm having a hard time getting used to.

Comment: Yeah there are some very neat built-in functions :)

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way would be to use the regex library `re`.  (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```
import re
pattern1 = re.compile(r'Bits received\s+(\d+)')  # \d means any digit character
pattern2 = re.compile(r'Bits in error\s+(\d+)')

with open('path/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    received = int(pattern1.match(text).group(1))
    in_error = int(pattern2.match(text).group(1))
    value_of_interest = in_error/received
```

This approach assumes that every input file has those two lines.  If that assumption can't be made, break up the `match`es to check for their presence:

```
match1 = pattern1.match(text)  # re.MatchObject if the pattern is found
if match1:  # None if it's not found
    received = int(match1.group(1))  # re.MatchObject.group(1) is the first parenthesized group
match2 = pattern2.match(text)
if match2:
    in_error = int(match2.group(1))
```